# Should ImmutableSortedSet throw an ArgumentNullException on Contains(null)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, icollection, immutable-collections

I have spent two days chasing down an evil bug. I narrowed down the problem with this test case demonstrating different behavior for different collection classes that implement the same interface. Specifically `Contains(null)` throws a `NullArgumentException` for `ImmutableSortedSet` but not for `Array` or the mutable `SortedSet`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Xunit;

public class SortedSetSpec
{
    [Fact]
    public void WTFNullCheck()
    {
        var data = new[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

        SortedSet<string> ss = new SortedSet<string>(data);
        ImmutableSortedSet<string> iss = ss.ToImmutableSortedSet();

        // This passes
        data.Contains(null).Should().BeFalse();

        // This passes
        ss.Contains(null).Should().BeFalse();

        // This throws an exception
        iss.Contains(null).Should().BeFalse();


    }
}
```

Given that all classes Array / SortedSet and ImmutableSortedSet implement `ICollection<T>` shouldn't they have the same behavior on the `Contains(null)` call?

The bug manifested itself when I data bound an `ImmutableSortedSet` to the `ItemsSource` property of a listbox.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Margin="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding WorkflowTags}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTag}" >
 </ListBox>
```

The problem is that at some point deep in the databinding code ListBox (aka Selector ) asks the collection `Contains(null)`?? and then it crashes if I've databound an `ImmutableSortedSet`.

So is this a bug with `ImmutableCollections` or with `WPF` or is it expected behavior and I should know better than to use `ImmutableSortedSet`?

The code within `ImmutableSortedSet` that is causing the problem can be found in the [corefx github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedSet_1.cs#L604)

```
/// <summary>
/// See the <see cref="IImmutableSet{T}"/> interface.
/// </summary>
public bool Contains(T value)
{
    Requires.NotNullAllowStructs(value, nameof(value));
    return _root.Contains(value, _comparer);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that because you can't *add* a null to an `ImmutableSortedSet<string>`, Microsoft have reasoned that you shouldn't be able to see if it contains a null.

Comment: I don't buy that. The ICollection interface where ``Contains`` is defined doesn't preclude asking if null is in there. I would accept that if you tried to add null to the collection it should throw but not asking if it contains null.

Comment: I've added a bug report at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15403

Comment: I'm just suggesting that's how Microsoft's thinking went; clearly it violates the Liskov substitution principle!

Comment: Sorry. I don't mean you are wrong. I mean the reasoning from the MS developer was wrong.